Is it true that Brahmi script is related to the Phoenician script?
Is it true that Brahmi script is related to the Phoenician scripts. Which are the other scripts that bear similarity to Brahmi script.
Which South Indian language writing system was most influenced by Brahmi.

According to Wikipedia the current consensus says Brahmi is descended from Aramaic script, though details are uncertain.  Aramaic and Phoenician (the languages and the alphabets) are closely related to each other.
Its descendants include all the scripts of South India among many others – though they may not look it!  Asking which of them is most influenced by their common ancestor is like asking which of the Romance languages is most influenced by Vulgar Latin.
